# Are there server side exception that are non-retryable?

Tags: rest, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I am designing a REST API and was looking to HTTP response code 500. It looks like the clients can retry such requests.

So now I am trying to understand if there are server-side error cases that clients should NOT retry. To me, it looks like everything apart from 501 are retryable. Even a coding bug in the server that results in an NPE still is retryable (considering the clients can retry once the bugs are fixed.)

1. What are the cases where service can throw an error (because of server-side issue) and ask clients not to retry?
2. In such cases, what HTTP response code is used in the industry? Should I use HTTP response code 500 and put additional details inside the response body to let clients know that they should not retry.

Comment: If the request is not idempontent, you should not retry since you would risk changes the client did not ask for.

Comment: @VaughanHilts: The question is how to communicate to the clients that they should not retry. And what are the server side failure scenarios where the server should say to the client that this request is not retryable.

For non-idempotent request if the client is making a request which is should not then the response will be 4XX instead of 5XX.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the scenarios on when should server throw an error and ask clients not to retry, I'll try to explain that with an example. Let's say the (application) server is making a call to a database (table) to eventually return a response to its clients. If by some manual error that table is deleted or if the table schema is changed such that the application is unable to return the response to its clients, then this should qualify for non-retryable server side exception. For the application server it is 4xx in the response from the Database. And for the clients, it is non-retryable server side exception.